# Populate dataGridView with a large set of results from SQL query in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, backgroundworker

I have a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) created with a dataGridView on it. I also have a long running SQL query that I am running in a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx) thread to populate a static datatable.

```
private void RunQuery_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(longRunningSQLQuery, datasourcename);
    adapter.Fill(results);
}

private void RunQuery_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = results;
}
```

This works perfectly fine. When I go to run the query, the UI remains responsive as the results are generated in the background... However, when it comes time to display the results in my dataGridView the window freezes if it's a large set of data. If I let it sit for a while, eventually it finishes. In my RunWorkerCompleted callback function, I call
`dataGridView1.DataSource = results;` (results is my DataSet) and this is the part that is taking a long time.

Is there any way I can pre-bind the dataGridView, or bind it in the backgroundworker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the Virtualmode of the datagrid, only the displayed rows are loaded. Otherwise, all rows will be loaded.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b177d6d.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It will use reflection to pull the values out of the data source.  A faster way may be to build and add the rows yourself.  You might be able to build a list of rows in the background thread, and then on the main UI thread add them as a range - not sure.

Obviously doing this you lose the benefits of data-binding, but if you want to load a mammoth amount of data, <strike>this could be the only option</strike>.  Turns out you can use VirtualMode, you implement parts yourself but keep the benefits of data-binding.

Answer (score 1):

Go for virtual mode as said by Run CMD. Here are couple of articles to get you started.

[Paging Data with DataGridView in VirtualMode](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridViewPaging.aspx)
[Walkthrough: Implementing Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx)
http://devintelligence.com/2007/02/displaying-large-amount-of-data-in-datagridview/

Answer (score 0):

Since a GridView is a visual component, I think the rule applies, that you can call the methods and properties only from within the foreground thread that created those controls.

Maybe you can do a filling of the grid in steps, adding each e.g. 100 records per iteration, making the control respond more smoothly.

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio seems to use a GridView, too, the handle large rows rather well.